# jQuery mobile library - buggy swipe detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

So I have an issue of in my code. I would like to detect right and left swipes only. I'm not interested in other events that the library provides.

I'm using the jQuery mobile library however it's buggy.

Behavior expected is for my code to detect right and left swipes.

Behavior received. First swipe is detected successfully, then not (or at least maybe yes maybe not..). Usually it detects first 3 swipes, then stops detecting them.

I noticed that after every single swipe, if you click in the browser/document then next swipe is garaunteed to be detected.

So if you click in the html document between swipes it works. If you do multiple swipes consequently without clicking/tapping it doesn't seem to work.

I tested this on Chrome version 43.x and Safari mobile browsers (Iphone and Laptop). I'm not sure how to fix this.

Things I tried:
To make sure not other script or something in my code causing this I made a jsfiddle with only the things concerning this event. Still same issue. I also tried different jQuery version.

I thought it might be focus issue, like after the alert pops up the document loses focus or something and you have to click inside it again. Trying setting focus to the div or the html document after each swipe/alert and it doesn't seem to have an effect.

I also thought maybe the alert is causing this, so I canceled the alert and added another way to detect swipes, like adding a counter for swipes detecting and populating an html element with the count each time a swipe is detected. Also no success.

JS FIDDLE :
https://jsfiddle.net/o1Ltq7oL/3/

HTML :

```
 <div class="container">
        Swipe Me
    </div>

<div id="counter"></div>
```

Javascript :

```
var count = 0;

$(".container").on("swipeleft",function(){
        count++;
        $("#counter").html(count);
    });

    $(".container").on("swiperight",function(){
        count++;
        $("#counter").html(count);
    });
```

css:

```
.container {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
}
```

external resources:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Would very much appreciate your input on the matter, and thank you very much in advance!

Comment: On what device are you testing? I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: I tried it on my laptop chrome version 43.x on laptop, firefox on laptop and on safari my Iphone. updated question.

Comment: So if you swipe let's say 10 times consequently on the swipe box all 10 get detected? for me it detects first 2-3 then not.

Comment: It looks like that one in 3-4 times it don't get triggered. Could you try with jQuery Mobile 1.4.2? https://jsfiddle.net/o1Ltq7oL/14/

Comment: Version 1.4.2 actually worked -.-' now I feel bad for not trying all versions before asking. I tried changing the jQuery library.. Can you please post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any information about bug like that but it looks like that this problem appeared in jQuery Mobile 1.4.4. Maybe you could try [HammerJS](http://hammerjs.github.io/) instead of jQuery Mobile.